# What is the format of Cloud Run service URLs?

Tags: google-cloud-run

[The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run#deploy_endpoints_proxy) gives an example of `https://gateway-12345-uc.a.run.app` as a service URL. Do Cloud Run service URLs always have the `-uc.a.run.app` suffix, or is this subject to change in the future?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The pattern is the following

```
https://<serviceName>-<projectHash>-<region>.run.app
```

Where

- ServiceName is the provided name of your service
- projectHash is generated by the Platform. You can't know it before the first deployment.  SHOULD never change, but sometime (and I don't know the reason, and it's just a caveats from Google) it can change in a different region
- region: is the region where you deployed. `uc.a` stand for us-central1. I have service in europe-west1 -> `ew.a`. I don't know the other region extensions, but deploy over there and you can easily find them.

Comment: Is the `projectHash` always gonna be there even if the `serviceName` is globally unique?

Comment: The service name is unique in a region AND a project. The project is represented by a hash. Have a try with another project if you want! So YES, the hash is mandatory

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Is there any way to get the projectHash at runtime?

Comment: It's possible to get it at runtime. Can you post a new question (and paste the link here), I will be able to share code with you.

Answer (score 1):

As of August 2022,

From the [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/https-request#creating_public_services) -

> The URL for a Cloud Run service has the format `https://[TAG---]SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.run.app`, where `TAG` refers to the traffic tag for the revision that you are requesting, and `SERVICE_IDENTIFIER` is a stable and unique identifier for a Cloud Run service. Do not parse the `SERVICE_IDENTIFIER` as it does not have a fixed format, and the logic for `SERVICE_IDENTIFIER` generation is subject to change.